# Placeholder is hidden (overwritten) inside the textarea when it scroll the contents in textarea

Tags: html, css, angular

[image: placeholder is hidden]

placeholder is hidden (overwritten) inside the textarea when it scroll the contents in textarea.

I need to fix the content to just below the placeholder when it scroll

```css
    css:
    .input-control-placeholder {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      padding: 7px 0 0 13px;
      color: #999ea4;
    }
    
    .form-label-group.col-12 input:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ label,
    .form-label-group.col-12 input:focus ~ label {
      padding-top: calc(var(--input-padding-y) / 3);
      padding-bottom: calc(var(--input-padding-y) / 3);
      font-size: 11px;
      color: #999ea4;
      padding-left: 7px !important;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="form-label-group col-8 pl-1 pr-1">
                  <textarea type="text" class="e-input input-control" formControlName="address" 
                        id="address" placeholder="address"></textarea>
    
                  <label class="input-control-placeholder" for="address" >Address</label  >
     </div>
```

Comment: Hey @Neethu, you want to hide the placeholder? Please explain your query and update the question.

Comment: Yes, you've said what's happening, but not what you _want_ to happen.

Comment: Can you please provide us the information of what you want us to help you with?

Comment: You should check this behavior in other browsers... Seems like a specific browser issue. I couldn't reproduce the issue in MS Edge.